# Logging or Extension of Selenium Webdriver actions

Tags: selenium, webdriver, action, extend, overwrite

Is there a way to overwrite or extend native Selenium WebDriver actions like 'click' or 'sendKeys' for logging purposes? So after performing a regular click or sendKeys following code would be triggered:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(className);
log.setLevel(logLevel);
log.info(strButtonName + " was clicked");
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact implementation would be language dependent, but you should be able to create a class which inherits WebDriver and then add extension methods or overloads which would preform the click and logging actions.